# Pyspark - Using reducebykey on spark dataframe column that is lists

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

So I have a spark dataframe called ngram_df that looks something like this

```
--------------------------------
 Name   | nGrams               |
--------|--------------------- |  
 Alice  | [ALI, LIC, ICE]      |
 Alicia | [ALI, LIC, ICI, CIA] |
--------------------------------
```

And I want to produce an output in a dictionary form such as:

> ALI: 2, LIC: 2, ICE: 1, ICI: 1, CIA: 1

I've been trying to turn the nGrams column into a RDD so that I can use the reduceByKey function

```
rdd = ngram_df.map(lambda row: row['nGrams'])
test = rdd.reduceByKey(add).collect()
```

However I get the error:

> ValueError: too many values to unpack

Even using flatmap doesn't help as I get the error:

> ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is possible with a combination of flatMap and reduceByKey method.

```
rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([('Alice', ['ALI', 'LIC', 'ICE']), ('Alicia', ['ALI', 'LIC', 'ICI', 'CIA'])])

result = rdd.flatMap(lambda x: [(y, 1) for y in x[1]] ).reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x+y)

result.collect()
[('ICI', 1), ('CIA', 1), ('ALI', 2), ('ICE', 1), ('LIC', 2)]
```